# 'ionicons/icons' does not contain an export named 'star'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, ionicons

I am using ionic react to make an app. When I want to add IonIcon it says

> 'ionicons/icons' does not contain an export named 'star'

Here is my code

```
import { IonApp, IonButton, IonContent, IonFooter, IonHeader, IonIcon, IonTitle, IonToolbar } 
from '@ionic/react';
import React from 'react';
import { star } from 'ionicons/icons';
const Home = () => {

return (
    <IonApp>
        <IonHeader translucent>
    <IonToolbar>
      <IonTitle>Home</IonTitle>
    </IonToolbar>
  </IonHeader>
        <IonContent>
            <h3>Hello</h3>
        </IonContent>
        <IonFooter>
            <IonToolbar>
                <IonButton> <IonIcon icon={star}> </IonIcon> Home</IonButton> 
            </IonToolbar>
        </IonFooter>
    </IonApp>
);
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the app firstly by npx creat-react-app then installed ionic-react on that. The icon was not showing on th file. But after creating an app by ionic start the icons are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you're using `Home` you're not importing it correctly.

`import Home from './home'`, not `import {Home} from './home'`

Or `Home` instead of `home`.

Comment: My data is showing correctly. Just icon is not showing because of the error